# How do I increase the max number of frames?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I'm currently working on a project that has a total of 304,593 frames, but when I fed this number into the timeline end point it reverted back to a solid 300,000. This is a hard limit for those wondering.

I cannot input more than this many frames, is there a way to override this? Including possible python options.

Comment: At 24 frames per second that would be about 3.5 hrs unless I did the math wrong, that's ambitious. Would that even fit on one DVD? I'd be surprised if it does.  Anyways, if you watch a movie closely, you'll likely see that the view changes every 3-5 seconds.  That's the camera/actors starting and stopping.  Afterwards, these short pieces are all spliced together to form a seamless whole.  Individually the shots are often less than a couple hundred frames each.

Comment: This is actually 60 frames per second, but still, it's a little over an hour. It's composed of several large individual pieces, it's not just one seamless whole. I'm editing them together.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This limit cannot be changed. You cannot alter builtin properties deriving from `bpy.types.Property`. Every attribute in [api docs](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_72_1/bpy.types.IntProperty.html?highlight=intproperty#bpy.types.IntProperty) is marked as readonly.
The scene's `frame_end` property hard and soft maximum is just set to 500,000*.

If you need to render longer video than that you will have to do that in another software.

Using negative frames or messing with time-remapping does not help.

---

**As of 2<sup>nd</sup> March 2016 the maximum is 500,000 (previously 300,000):

https://developer.blender.org/rBf7062b2407c65dcf85904242281a13339d47a20a*

Comment: I thought Blender was open source. Is there no way to edit these files anyway (readonly can be changed) via some sort of editing program or something that can change the readonly attribute?

Comment: @Jerryno is it possible to use the negative frames; "i know it's for playback only" but if there is trick to shift all the time line to enable the render at the end

Comment: I tried negative frames, hard limit was set at 0 unless I missed something.

Comment: it is for playback only you should enable it from the settings under editing tab

Comment: Doesn't sound like it would solve the problem. I could render two large pieces but would need another piece of software to stick them together. My goal is to use Blender throughout this entire process, which is why I started with it.

Comment: @meed96 yes you could modify the blender source files, but first I would check with the devs if its safe or how best to do it..

Comment: MAXFRAME is defined in [DNA_scene_types.h](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/makesdna/DNA_scene_types.h) line 1520.

Comment: Just done a quick test, increased MAXFRAME and rebuilt. I added a short sequence to the vse and duplicated it many times, at 320459 frames I rendered to a H264 file without issue. It was only 320x180 but I had no problems. You may see some small limits as far as not being able to see the entire strip in the vse or timeline.